# Cannot assign loop results into array properly

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following dataframe

```
          genome1        genome2  percent1  percent2        ANI
0   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.35  99.095220
1   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.40  98.495660
2   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.45  98.669918
3   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.50  98.500838
4   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.55  98.601606
5   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.60  98.722015
6   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.65  98.730725
7   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.70  98.682221
8   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.75  99.094596
9   GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.80  98.828468
10  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.85  99.090124
11  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.90  99.112024
12  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      0.95  99.192380
13  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.10      1.00  99.376812
14  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.20  97.009700
15  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.25  97.244750
16  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.30  97.904578
17  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.35  98.077026
18  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.40  98.348245
19  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.45  98.280009
20  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.50  98.434687
21  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.55  98.491112
22  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.60  98.547068
23  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.65  98.650248
24  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.70  98.878492
25  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.75  98.897532
26  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.80  98.985684
27  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.85  99.038040
28  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.90  99.233776
29  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      0.95  99.245952
30  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.15      1.00  99.397208
31  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.15  97.806960
32  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.20  98.707025
33  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.25  98.452431
34  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.30  97.922750
35  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.35  98.095552
36  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.40  97.911546
37  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.45  98.189728
38  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.50  98.340308
39  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.55  98.437920
40  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.60  98.542968
41  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.65  98.847280
42  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.70  98.859392
43  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.75  98.952128
44  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.80  98.908232
45  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.85  99.173704
46  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.90  99.265132
47  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      0.95  99.287808
48  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.20      1.00  99.408728
49  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.10  98.555500
50  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.15  98.502583
51  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.20  98.082729
52  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.25  98.075705
53  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.30  98.105842
54  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.35  98.145436
55  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.40  98.605504
56  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.45  98.638808
57  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.50  98.548068
58  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.55  98.717488
59  GCA_000969925  GCF_000969885      0.25      0.60  98.949116
              ...            ...       ...       ...        ...
```

I would like to create a matrix indicating the percent from 0.05 to 1.00 by  0.05 steps and assign values for which percent of genomes have ANI value > 95.

I've tried iterating with two loops, like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

results = pd.read_csv(...)

matrix = np.zeros((20, 20))
m_i=0
m_j=0

for i in np.arange(0.05, 1.01, 0.05):
    for j in np.arange(0.05, 1.01, 0.05):
        #print(i, j)
        df=results[(results.percent1 == i) & (results.percent2 == j)]
        if not df.empty:
            above=len(df.genome1[df.ANI > 95].unique())
            total=len(df.genome1.unique())
            per_above_95=above/total*100
            matrix[i][j]=per_above_95
            m_j += 1
        else:
            continue
    m_i += 1

print(matrix)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a matrix with the first 2x2 values has 100s and the rest are 0s.

I would like to get a 20x20 matrix like this:

```
     0.05 0.10 0.15 ...
0.05  0   10    25
0.10  10  33    45
0.15  25  45    66
...
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the line `matrix[i][j]=per_above_95` is copied correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I hope it's not something silly :(

Comment: Please post a minimum, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, you might want to use the dataframe `nunique()` method instead of `len()`. The obvious conclusion to draw is that you are failing the if check after the 2x2 square, so think why that might be happening.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is just a huge problem with the logic of your program. You only have 3 items in your i and j loops, so only a 3x3 square is being filled. Your m_i and m_j indexes are doing nothing. You need to think more carefully about what should be happening in each loop and why.

Comment: Okay so it looks from your code like you're trying to do a C / Java style loop with manual incrementing, but in Python it's more typical to just loop over a range: `for i in range(20):` will loop over 0, 1, ..., 19 with i updating at the end of each loop. You can also do `for i, item in enumerate(['a', 'b', c']):` which will give you `i=0, item='a'`, `i=1, item='b'`, etc. - perhaps this loop format is appropriate for your task? At the moment your loop makes no sense (`m_i` and `m_j` are redundant), so it's impossible to debug further until you fix this.

Comment: That's weird, do you why when I write: results[(results.percent1 == 0.9) & (results.percent2 == 0.95)]  in the command line I get the right table, but when the loop is in i = 0.9 and j = 0.95 I get empty table?